# Sci-Fi short story of woman who transformed into a male then back

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

I remember reading this story quite a while ago. A married woman with two children was bored with life and decided to see what it would be like to be a man. She went to a local store to get a body scan to see what her male body would look like based on her body's composition. She decided on a little less muscle and came home as a man, much to her husbands shock. I believe she called herself Leo. She didn't stay male long, I remember one day her husband came home to find her as a woman again.

What was the title and who was the author???

Comment: How long ago was "quite a while ago"? Do you remember if you read this in a book, or in a magazine, or perhaps online?

Answer (score 14):

This is the Hugo and Locus nominated "[Options](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41090)" by John Varley, written in 1979.

> Technology has enabled the populace of Betaville to change ones sex as
> easily as changing ones clothes. So when Cleo Lawson finds that her
> husband is a philanderer she takes the opportunity to change her sex [to Leo]
> as a means to understanding what it is to be a man, and perhaps why
> her husband is the way he is.

You can read it online [here](http://socrates.bmcc.cuny.edu/jbisz/websiteBB/Options_01/Options-Varley.pdf)

---

It may interest you to know that the story was made into a TV show in the anthology sci-fi series "Welcome to Paradox".

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much!! I'll check out that series, too.