# Wanting Title for Futuristic Sex Change Story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, sexuality

15-20 years ago there was an anthology series on the SciFi channel. One episode in the series featured a story about a married couple. For whatever reason the wife wanted to change her sex to male. She went to this clinic that specialized in sex changes. They created a holographic image of what you wanted your body to be according to your specifications. They then gave her a series of injections and her body was placed in a chamber. 
Sometime later she emerged as the male she wanted to be. Her husband was resistant to this and to her desire for him to become female. In the end he gives in.

The TV show was based on a short story. The story was basically the same, except the transition was made by means of making a clone of the person with altered X-Y chromosomes. When the clone was mature, a brain transplant was performed. I'm drawing a blank about names. Does anyone recall the name of this series and episode, if it's available on YouTube, etc.and what the name of the original short story and author is?

Comment: That series/episode has been asked and answered on this site before, although I don't have the time to find it.

Answer (score 8):

The John Varley story [Options](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41090) contains all the elements you describe of a married couple where the female partner desires to undergo a sex change against the wishes of the male partner.

An episode in the 1985 television series [Welcome to Paradox](https://varley.net/film/options-2/) was based on this story.  This series aired on the Sci-Fi channel.

Comment: Has that been asked here before then?

Comment: @Adamant https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/128629/19561